# Gnuplot gives 2 instead of 24 columns with an other timeformat

Tags: time, format, gnuplot

I have the next problem. I had an datafile like;

```
1412481600,304,0,0,0,304,0
1412485200,385,0,0,0,383,0
1412488800,332,0,0,0,331,0
1412492400,359,0,0,0,355,0
```

I have changed the format to;

```
08-11-2014-17:00,390,0,27,417
08-11-2014-18:00,474,0,0,474
08-11-2014-19:00,467,0,0,467
08-11-2014-20:00,687,0,0,687
```

I changed either the gnuplotscript.

First was;

`set timefmt x "%s"`

To now in;

`set timefmt x "%d-%m-%Y-%H:%M"`

In the new situation gnuplot gives me 2 columns they are overwrite
with other columns.
What am I doing wrong or I forget ?

Here the working en wrong example;
[image: good and wrong]

And this is the complete code;

```
file = 'uur.txt'
set output "dag.png"
set datafile separator ","
set linestyle 1 lt 1 lc rgb "black" 
set bmargin 5 # witruimte onder grafiek

set boxwidth 600 absolute
set style boxplot
set border back

dy=500 # zie y waarde terminal
# Hier worden de maximale en minimale y-waarden van gnuplot bepaald.
set terminal unknown
plot "<tail -24 ".file."" using :(-$5) w p, '' u :4 w p
ymax= GPVAL_Y_MAX
ymin= GPVAL_Y_MIN
ptmax=ymax*dy/(ymax-ymin)
ptmin=ymin*dy/(ymax-ymin)
replot

set terminal pngcairo truecolor enhanced size 1200, 500 font "Courier Bold,10" background rgb "#CFCFFF"



stats "<tail -24 ".file."" using 2:3 nooutput
afnt = STATS_sum_x
gelt = STATS_sum_y
afn  = afnt/24
gel  = gelt/24

stats "< tail -24 ".file."" using 4:5 nooutput
zon    = STATS_max_x
zont   = STATS_sum_x
geb    = STATS_max_y
gebt   = STATS_sum_y
zonavg = STATS_sum_x/24
gebavg = STATS_sum_y/24

stats "<tail -1 ".file."" using (strptime('%d-%m-%y %H:%M', stringcolumn(1))) nooutput
tijd = strftime('%H:%M', STATS_max)

set palette defined (-(geb) "#ee0000", 0 "#0000cc", 0 "#00aa00", (zon) "#ff0000")
unset colorbox

set title 'Alle energie-stromen van de laatste 24 uur.' font "Courier-Bold,12"

set xdata time
set timefmt '%d-%m-%y-%H:%M'
set xtics format "%H:%M"  # dit is de opmaak zoals je hem gaat zien
set xtics 3600
set mxtics 0 # zet sub(minor)streepjes op de x-as 
set grid ls 1 lw 1 lc rgb "#a0a0a0"
set autoscale xfix

set ytics font "Helvetica,8"
set mytics 2
set y2tics axis out 0

set ylabel "V e r m o g e n in Watt" offset 2,1

set object rect from screen 0.05, screen 0.04 to screen 0.08, screen 0.06 fc rgb '#00B900' front
set object rect from sc 0.05, sc 0.01 to sc 0.08, sc 0.03 fc rgb 'blue' front
set object rect from sc 0.25, sc 0.04 to sc 0.28, sc 0.06 fc rgb 'green'
set object 10 rect from sc 0.25, sc 0.01 to sc 0.28, sc 0.03  fc rgb "red" fs solid 1.0 front
set object 10 rect from sc 0.25, sc 0.01 to sc 0.28, sc 0.03  fc rgb "#5555ff" fs solid 1.0 front

# graph x, y
set label font "Courier Bold, 10" # grootte font tbv labels in het grafiek
set label  1 sprintf("Energiestromen gemiddeld per uur.") at screen 0.05,0.08 tc rgb "black" front
set label  2 sprintf("Zon      = %4.0f W/h",zonavg) at screen 0.085,0.05 front
set label  3 sprintf("Gebruikt = %4.0f W/h",gebavg) at screen 0.085,0.025 front
set label  4 sprintf("Geleverd  = %4.0f W/h",gel) at screen 0.285,0.05 front
set label  5 sprintf("Afgenomen = %4.0f W/h",afn) at screen 0.285,0.025 front
set label  6 sprintf("Energiestromen van de afgelopen 24 uur.") at screen 0.5,0.08 front
set label  7 sprintf("Gebruikt (%dW) = zon (%dW) - geleverd (%dW) + afgenomen (%dW)", gebt, zont, gelt, afnt) at screen 0.5,0.05  tc rgb "black" front
set label 11 sprintf("Logtijd: ") at screen 0.05,0.92 font "Courier-Bold,8" front
set label 12 sprintf(tijd) at screen 0.091,0.92 font "Courier-Bold,8" front

set style fill solid noborder# was transparent solid 0.5 border 0.5

n = 51
# n is het aantal kolommen wat wordt opgebouwd teneinde een gradient te krijgen. Hoe hoger "n" des te vloeiender de gradient
# De 1e serie is zon, de 2e serie is geleverd, de 3e serie is gebruik en de 4e serie is afgenomen.
# Het getal 12 is het aantal punten van één karakter Courier-Bold 10 hetgeen hier is gebruikt voor de labels.

plot for [i=n:0:-1] "<tail -24 ".file."" u ($1-600):(($4/n)*i):(($4/n)*i) w boxes lc palette notitle,\
            "<tail -24 ".file."" u ($1-600):4:( $4>0 && ($4/ymax*ptmax)> (12 * strlen(sprintf("%d", $4))) ? $4 : sprintf("")) w labels right rotate font ",10" tc rgb "white" offset 0,-0.1 notitle,\
            "<tail -24 ".file."" u ($1-600):4:( $4>0 && ($4/ymax*ptmax)<=(12 * strlen(sprintf("%d", $4))) ? $4 : sprintf("")) w labels  left rotate font ",10" tc rgb "black" offset 0,0.1  notitle,\
            "<tail -24 ".file."" u ($1-600):4 w boxes lc rgb "black" fill empty  notitle,\
            "<tail -24 ".file."" u ($1+600):3 w boxes lt 1 lc rgb "green" fillstyle solid  notitle,\
            "<tail -24 ".file."" u ($1+600):3 w boxes lc rgb "black" fill empty notitle,\
            "<tail -24 ".file."" u ($1+600):3:( $3>0 && ($3/ymax*ptmax)> (12 * strlen(sprintf("%d", $3))) ? $3 : sprintf("")) w labels right rotate font ",10" tc rgb "blue"  offset 0,-0.1 notitle,\
            "<tail -24 ".file."" u ($1+600):3:( $3>0 && ($3/ymax*ptmax)<=(12 * strlen(sprintf("%d", $3))) ? $3 : sprintf("")) w labels  left rotate font ",10" tc rgb "black" offset 0,0.1  notitle,\
     for [i=n:0:-1] "<tail -24 ".file."" u ($1-600):((-($5)/n)*i):((-($5)/n)*i) w boxes lc palette notitle,\
            "<tail -24 ".file."" u ($1-600):(-$5):( $5>0 && ($5/ymax*ptmax)> (12 * strlen(sprintf("%d", $5))) ? -$5 : sprintf("")) w labels left  rotate font ",10" tc rgb "white" offset 0,0.1  notitle,\
            "<tail -24 ".file."" u ($1-600):(-$5):( $5>0 && ($5/ymax*ptmax)<=(12 * strlen(sprintf("%d", $5))) ? -$5 : sprintf("")) w labels right rotate font ",10" tc rgb "black" offset 0,-0.1 notitle,\
            "<tail -24 ".file."" u ($1-600):(-$5) w boxes lc rgb "black" fill empty  notitle,\
            "<tail -24 ".file."" u ($1+600):(-$2) w boxes lc rgb "#5555ff" fillstyle solid notitle,\
            "<tail -24 ".file."" u ($1+600):(-$2) w boxes lc rgb "black" fill empty notitle,\
            "<tail -24 ".file."" u ($1+600):(-$2):( $2>0 && ($2/ymax*ptmax)> (12 * strlen(sprintf("%d", $2))) ? -$2 : sprintf("")) w labels left  rotate font ",10" tc rgb "white" offset 0,0.1  notitle,\
            "<tail -24 ".file."" u ($1+600):(-$2):( $2>0 && ($2/ymax*ptmax)<=(12 * strlen(sprintf("%d", $2))) ? -$2 : sprintf("")) w labels right rotate font ",10" tc rgb "black" offset 0,-0.1 notitle
```

The complete datafile can you find here: http://ccvd.eu/downloads/uur.txt

Comment: What you did so far seems to be OK. But it is hard to say what's wrong with your code if you do not post it. Due to the complexity of your plot, you may post / try a simple example where you just plot data vs. time. One guess: You separated your colums by `,` while gnuplot expects white spaces. You can change this by `set datafile separator ","
`

Comment: Thanx for your reaction, I have put the code in my original post.

Comment: That script is still far too complex. We don't want to debug your whole script. And without having any data we also cannot reproduce this. One point could be, that for the `stats` command you use a timeformat of `%d-%m-%y %H:%M`. Possibly this should be the same as your general timefmt, i.e. `%d-%m-%Y-%H:%M`.

Comment: I am sorry, that makes no difference. I put the link to the datafile in my post, hopefully you can do something with it here. I'm very curious for the solution. Thanks (again) in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems: First you must use the correct time format `%d-%m-%Y-%H:%M` in all cases (in the script you posted, you have a small `y`, and in the stats command you are missing a dash).

And, second, you must use `timecolumn(1)` instead of `$1` in the `using` statement in order to have the date parsed correctly. When you had a timestamp, it worked fine since it was only a number, but parsing of the string failed. So your complete script should be

```
file = 'uur.txt'
set output "dag.png"
set datafile separator ","
set linestyle 1 lt 1 lc rgb "black" 
set bmargin 5 # witruimte onder grafiek

set boxwidth 600 absolute
set style boxplot
set border back

dy=500 # zie y waarde terminal
# Hier worden de maximale en minimale y-waarden van gnuplot bepaald.
set terminal unknown
plot "<tail -24 ".file."" using :(-$5) w p, '' u :4 w p
ymax= GPVAL_Y_MAX
ymin= GPVAL_Y_MIN
ptmax=ymax*dy/(ymax-ymin)
ptmin=ymin*dy/(ymax-ymin)
replot

set terminal pngcairo truecolor enhanced size 1200, 500 font "Courier Bold,10" background rgb "#CFCFFF"



stats "<tail -24 ".file."" using 2:3 nooutput
afnt = STATS_sum_x
gelt = STATS_sum_y
afn  = afnt/24
gel  = gelt/24

stats "< tail -24 ".file."" using 4:5 nooutput
zon    = STATS_max_x
zont   = STATS_sum_x
geb    = STATS_max_y
gebt   = STATS_sum_y
zonavg = STATS_sum_x/24
gebavg = STATS_sum_y/24

stats "<tail -1 ".file."" using (strptime('%d-%m-%Y-%H:%M', stringcolumn(1))) nooutput
tijd = strftime('%H:%M', STATS_max)

set palette defined (-(geb) "#ee0000", 0 "#0000cc", 0 "#00aa00", (zon) "#ff0000")
unset colorbox

set title 'Alle energie-stromen van de laatste 24 uur.' font "Courier-Bold,12"

set xdata time
set timefmt '%d-%m-%Y-%H:%M'
set xtics format "%H:%M"  # dit is de opmaak zoals je hem gaat zien
set xtics 3600
set mxtics 0 # zet sub(minor)streepjes op de x-as 
set grid ls 1 lw 1 lc rgb "#a0a0a0"
set autoscale xfix

set ytics font "Helvetica,8"
set mytics 2
set y2tics axis out 0

set ylabel "V e r m o g e n in Watt" offset 2,1

set object rect from screen 0.05, screen 0.04 to screen 0.08, screen 0.06 fc rgb '#00B900' front
set object rect from sc 0.05, sc 0.01 to sc 0.08, sc 0.03 fc rgb 'blue' front
set object rect from sc 0.25, sc 0.04 to sc 0.28, sc 0.06 fc rgb 'green'
set object 10 rect from sc 0.25, sc 0.01 to sc 0.28, sc 0.03  fc rgb "red" fs solid 1.0 front
set object 10 rect from sc 0.25, sc 0.01 to sc 0.28, sc 0.03  fc rgb "#5555ff" fs solid 1.0 front

# graph x, y
set label font "Courier Bold, 10" # grootte font tbv labels in het grafiek
set label  1 sprintf("Energiestromen gemiddeld per uur.") at screen 0.05,0.08 tc rgb "black" front
set label  2 sprintf("Zon      = %4.0f W/h",zonavg) at screen 0.085,0.05 front
set label  3 sprintf("Gebruikt = %4.0f W/h",gebavg) at screen 0.085,0.025 front
set label  4 sprintf("Geleverd  = %4.0f W/h",gel) at screen 0.285,0.05 front
set label  5 sprintf("Afgenomen = %4.0f W/h",afn) at screen 0.285,0.025 front
set label  6 sprintf("Energiestromen van de afgelopen 24 uur.") at screen 0.5,0.08 front
set label  7 sprintf("Gebruikt (%dW) = zon (%dW) - geleverd (%dW) + afgenomen (%dW)", gebt, zont, gelt, afnt) at screen 0.5,0.05  tc rgb "black" front
set label 11 sprintf("Logtijd: ") at screen 0.05,0.92 font "Courier-Bold,8" front
set label 12 sprintf(tijd) at screen 0.091,0.92 font "Courier-Bold,8" front

set style fill solid noborder# was transparent solid 0.5 border 0.5

n = 51
# n is het aantal kolommen wat wordt opgebouwd teneinde een gradient te krijgen. Hoe hoger "n" des te vloeiender de gradient
# De 1e serie is zon, de 2e serie is geleverd, de 3e serie is gebruik en de 4e serie is afgenomen.
# Het getal 12 is het aantal punten van één karakter Courier-Bold 10 hetgeen hier is gebruikt voor de labels.

plot for [i=n:0:-1] "<tail -24 ".file."" u (timecolumn(1)-600):(($4/n)*i):(($4/n)*i) w boxes lc palette notitle,\
            "<tail -24 ".file."" u (timecolumn(1)-600):4:( $4>0 && ($4/ymax*ptmax)> (12 * strlen(sprintf("%d", $4))) ? $4 : sprintf("")) w labels right rotate font ",10" tc rgb "white" offset 0,-0.1 notitle,\
            "<tail -24 ".file."" u (timecolumn(1)-600):4:( $4>0 && ($4/ymax*ptmax)<=(12 * strlen(sprintf("%d", $4))) ? $4 : sprintf("")) w labels  left rotate font ",10" tc rgb "black" offset 0,0.1  notitle,\
            "<tail -24 ".file."" u (timecolumn(1)-600):4 w boxes lc rgb "black" fill empty  notitle,\
            "<tail -24 ".file."" u (timecolumn(1)+600):3 w boxes lt 1 lc rgb "green" fillstyle solid  notitle,\
            "<tail -24 ".file."" u (timecolumn(1)+600):3 w boxes lc rgb "black" fill empty notitle,\
            "<tail -24 ".file."" u (timecolumn(1)+600):3:( $3>0 && ($3/ymax*ptmax)> (12 * strlen(sprintf("%d", $3))) ? $3 : sprintf("")) w labels right rotate font ",10" tc rgb "blue"  offset 0,-0.1 notitle,\
            "<tail -24 ".file."" u (timecolumn(1)+600):3:( $3>0 && ($3/ymax*ptmax)<=(12 * strlen(sprintf("%d", $3))) ? $3 : sprintf("")) w labels  left rotate font ",10" tc rgb "black" offset 0,0.1  notitle,\
     for [i=n:0:-1] "<tail -24 ".file."" u (timecolumn(1)-600):((-($5)/n)*i):((-($5)/n)*i) w boxes lc palette notitle,\
            "<tail -24 ".file."" u (timecolumn(1)-600):(-$5):( $5>0 && ($5/ymax*ptmax)> (12 * strlen(sprintf("%d", $5))) ? -$5 : sprintf("")) w labels left  rotate font ",10" tc rgb "white" offset 0,0.1  notitle,\
            "<tail -24 ".file."" u (timecolumn(1)-600):(-$5):( $5>0 && ($5/ymax*ptmax)<=(12 * strlen(sprintf("%d", $5))) ? -$5 : sprintf("")) w labels right rotate font ",10" tc rgb "black" offset 0,-0.1 notitle,\
            "<tail -24 ".file."" u (timecolumn(1)-600):(-$5) w boxes lc rgb "black" fill empty  notitle,\
            "<tail -24 ".file."" u (timecolumn(1)+600):(-$2) w boxes lc rgb "#5555ff" fillstyle solid notitle,\
            "<tail -24 ".file."" u (timecolumn(1)+600):(-$2) w boxes lc rgb "black" fill empty notitle,\
            "<tail -24 ".file."" u (timecolumn(1)+600):(-$2):( $2>0 && ($2/ymax*ptmax)> (12 * strlen(sprintf("%d", $2))) ? -$2 : sprintf("")) w labels left  rotate font ",10" tc rgb "white" offset 0,0.1  notitle,\
            "<tail -24 ".file."" u (timecolumn(1)+600):(-$2):( $2>0 && ($2/ymax*ptmax)<=(12 * strlen(sprintf("%d", $2))) ? -$2 : sprintf("")) w labels right rotate font ",10" tc rgb "black" offset 0,-0.1 notitle
```

with the expected output of

[image]

Comment: Perfect, I knew you'd find out. Thank you so much, your knowledge is incredible about gnuplot!

Comment: *sigh*, I knew you'd pass me up eventually.  I wish I was still using gnuplot -- and on my way to gnuplot gold!  Congrats :-).

Comment: @mgilson Thanks :) However, there is still some way to go for gnuplot gold... I finished my thesis half a year ago, who knows how long I'll keep up with gnuplot development ;)